# Rewrite rule causing a not found error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment, when I visit `example.com/index.php?page_id=6726`, the desired page is displayed. I would like to rewrite the URL to the format of `example.com/newsletter`.

My current .htaccess file includes this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\/newsletter [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page_id=6726 [NC,QSA]
```

Yet, I receive a page not found error.

How can I make the rewrite work so that when I visit `example.com/newsletter` the content of `example.com/index.php?page_id=6726` is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^newsletter$ index.php?page_id=6272 [L,NC]
```

More generally, if the `page_id` is a variable, so

```
 RewriteRule ^newsletter/?(\d+)?$ index.php?page_id=$1 [L,NC]
```

will redirect the visitor to many similar pages, such as

```
example.com/newsletter/6272  -> example.com/index.php?page_id=6272
example.com/newsletter/272  -> example.com/index.php?page_id=272
example.com/newsletter/627  -> example.com/index.php?page_id=627
...
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I am looking for. When `example.com/newsletter` I want this page's  `example.com/index.php?page_id=6726` content to display in `example.com/newsletter`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When a user visits `example.com/newsletter/6272`, Apache loads the page at `index.php?page_id=6272`, but the user can only see `example.com/newsletter/6272`, not  `index.php?page_id=6272`, so user does not know you are using `PHP` or the file is `index.php`

Comment: Ok, but I would prefer to have it called as `example.com/newsletter` and not `example.com/newsletter/6726`.

Comment: if `6272` is a constant, you can just use `RewriteRule ^newsletter$ index.php?page_id=6272 [L,NC]`

Comment: I still get a page not found. Because it is multi domain path, is it possible that I need to add the domain the regex? Even `RewriteRule ^domain\.com\/newsletter$ index.php?page_id=6726 [L,NC]` results in page not found.